# Responsive YouTube video embed to website using only HTML

Tags: html, web, youtube, embed

I am trying to add responsive YouTube video embeds to my website. The catch is, I can only use HTML. The website designer I am using only has an HTML widget for me to utilize. I want the width of the YouTube video to be full width on Mobile but only 800px on desktop. And their heights should be relative as well in order to not mess up the aspect ratio. Everything centered as well. Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:

```
<center>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r0L_HCLnzas" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</center>
```

Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more.

Comment: Oh dang! Thanks for letting me know. I had looked up how to center everything that was the top result to come up. Strange that after being obsolete for 15 years it still ranks at the top of google.